# How can I change the primary GPU in both Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: bios, gpu, integrated-graphics, asus, priority

I have an AMD 7950X CPU that has a built-in GPU. Also a dedicated 4090 GPU. I have also a monitor with 2 input HDMI ports that I have used to connect my Asus ProArt X670E( For CPU built-in GPU) to one and 4090 GPU to the other.

The problem is both OSes detect the Nvidia GPU as the primary GPU and use it for the display, but I want to use the CPU built-in GPU for the display.

I tried `prime-select intel` on Ubuntu but the result was a blank screen after reboot. I also tried to prioritize GPUs from BIOS but I couldn't fine `Graphics Configuration` or `System Agent Configuration` options over there. I use the latest firmware I believe.

Does anyone know how can I priorities GPUs in each of these OSes or within the ASUS ProArt BIOS settings?

Comment: For some computers, you can do it in the BIOS/UEFI. Boot into it and check for a section about Graphics or Advanced. If unclear what to do, for some this means switching from PEG to IGD.